# American Put question

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

If the interest rate is zero. Then show that the optimal exercise for an american put option is always the terminal time. That is, it is equivalent to a european put option.

Answer (score 1):

If the interest rate is zero, there is never a reason to exercise your put early, so you can price it as a European put.